# Tkinter: image loop slows down

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a Tkinter GUI that is supposed to show display 3D images by looping through the 2D slices of each 3D image. I read up on how to implement such an image loop, and it was recommended to use the `after()` function with recursion. This is, in principle, my implementation of that:

```
def load_image(self):
    self.stack = read_3D_image(path)
    slice = self.stack[self.slice_no]
    im = Image.fromarray(slice)
    self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im)
    self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photo, anchor=tk.NW)
    if self.forward is True:
        self.slice_no += 1
        if self.slice_no == 21:
            self.forward = False
    if self.forward is False:
        self.slice_no -= 1
        if self.slice_no == 0:
            self.forward = True
    root.after(10, self.load_image)
```

This works well for some time, but after a couple of minutes, the loop notably slows down. I guess that is because of the high number of iterations. Is there a way to fix this?

Edit: I noticed this: when the program runs, the image loop will slow down to about half the original frequency after about 10 minutes. When I run a second instance, its loop runs equally slow. Then when I close the first instance, the second instance loop immediately runs faster. I launch from Eclipse.

**Updated full code**

```
import glob
import os.path
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy as np

import helpers


class App():

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()
        self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
        master.bind("<KP_1>", lambda e: self.is_cell())
        master.bind("<KP_2>", lambda e: self.is_not_cell())
        self.frame.pack()

        self.goto_button = tk.Button(
            self.frame, text="Go to:", command=self.goto)
        self.goto_button.pack(side=tk.TOP)

        self.goto_entry = tk.Entry(self.frame, width=5)
        self.goto_entry.pack(side=tk.TOP)

        self.img_side_length = 100

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(
            master=self.frame, width=self.img_side_length, height=self.img_side_length)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.img_label = tk.Label(self.frame, text="Bla")
        self.img_label.pack(side=tk.TOP)

        self.no_cell_button = tk.Button(
            self.frame, text="2: Not cell!", command=self.is_not_cell)
        self.no_cell_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

        self.cell_button = tk.Button(
            self.frame, text="1: Cell!", command=self.is_cell)
        self.cell_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)



        self.img_path = "/storage/images/"
        self.img_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.img_path, "*"))
        self.img_list.sort()
        self.slice_no = 0
        self.img_no = 0
        self.forward = True
        self.no_of_imgs = len(self.img_list)
        self.stack = []
        self.image_id = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW)
        self.stack = helpers.read_image_sequence(self.img_list[self.img_no])

        self.classifications = np.zeros(self.no_of_imgs)

        self.out_path = "/dev/null"

        self.loop_image()

    def loop_image(self):

        data = self.stack[self.slice_no]
        im = Image.fromarray(data)
        im = im.resize((self.img_side_length, self.img_side_length))
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im)
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.image_id, image=self.photo)
        if self.forward is True:
            self.slice_no += 1
            if self.slice_no == 21:
                self.forward = False
        if self.forward is False:
            self.slice_no -= 1
            if self.slice_no == 0:
                self.forward = True
        root.after(10, self.loop_image)

    def next_image(self):
        self.img_no += 1
        self.stack = helpers.read_image_sequence(self.img_list[self.img_no])
        self.img_label['text'] = self.img_list[self.img_no].split("/")[-1]

    def previous_image(self):
        self.img_no -= 1
        self.stack = helpers.read_image_sequence(self.img_list[self.img_no])
        self.img_label['text'] = self.img_list[self.img_no].split("/")[-1]

    def is_cell(self):
        self.classifications[self.img_no] = 1
        with open(self.out_path, "a") as f:
            f.write(str(self.img_no) + "," + str(1) + "\n")
        print(self.classifications)
        self.next_image()

    def is_not_cell(self):
        self.classifications[self.img_no] = 2
        with open(self.out_path, "a") as f:
            f.write(str(self.img_no) + "," + str(2) + "\n")
        print(self.classifications)
        self.next_image()


    def goto(self):
        self.img_no = int(self.goto_entry.get())


root = tk.Tk()

app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Recursion?  There is no recursion here... The problem is that you are just piling new images on top of the old ones; you either need to delete the previous canvas image item each time you create a new one, or maintain a single canvas item that you simply change the `image` attribute of.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks! Yes it's recursive, `load_image` is calling itself in the last line.

Comment: No, it is not calling itself - that would be an almost instant stack overflow error.  It's scheduling itself to be called later; the actual call is being performed by Tkinter's event loop.

Comment: speedymcs: The `root.after()` isn't calling `load_image`, it's just scheduling a call to it later—so it's not recursion, it's looping.

Comment: I see, thanks! Makes more sense.. if the function were stalling and then calling itself, you wouldn't be able to use any other GUI element, I guess? I now added the line `self.canvas.delete("all")` before its image creation, but the loop will still slow down after some time

Answer (score 3):

You are creating 100 images per second and are stacking them on top of each other. After 10 minutes, that's 60,000 images stacked on top of each other. The canvas has performance issues when it has tens of thousands of items on it, even if all but one is invisible.

Instead of creating more and more images on the canvas, just modify the existing image:

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(...)
    ...
    # create the image object which will display the image
    self.image_id = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW)

def load_image(self):
    ...
    self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im)

    # reconfigure the canvas item to show the new image
    canvas.itemconfigure(self.image_id, image=self.photo)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. This results in an exception: 

self.canvas.configure(self.image_id, self.photo)

TypeError: configure() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: @speedymcs: my mistake. That should be `itemconfigure` along with `image=self.photo`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Now the same line throws: TypeError: object of type 'PhotoImage' has no len()

Comment: @speedymcs: unfortunately, I don't get that error. I've tried it in python2 and python3. My guess is you left out the `image=` part.

Comment: It works now! I have no idea why, maybe I f`ed something up before. Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately, the loop will still slow down to half the speed and less after a couple of minutes. I updated the question with the current full code.